# How to use BaseXpath object access data in OMElement object

Tags: java, dom, xpath, axiom

I need to validate data inside string xpath expression.

```
SimpleVariableContext svc=new SimpleVariableContext();
svc.setVariableValue("part1", xpathBodyElements[0]);
String completedXPath="$part1";
BaseXPath  contextpath=new BaseXPath(completedXPath,nav);
contextpath.setVariableContext(svc);
```

Now  I have the validated Xpath object. I have a OMElement which contains the xml structure. I want to get the specific element defined in the basexpath. How can I access OMElement with BaseXPath object ?

Can I cast BaseXpath object to AxiomXPAth element ?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show how `nav` is initialized.